# Possible to upgrade to Windows 10 again after first upgrade was declined at EULA screen?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

One of my computers got automatically upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10 overnight. I wanted to upgrade it soon, but not today, because I need to have it running and available as it is.

Windows 10 now waits at initial EULA screen to accept/decline the EULA.
**When I decline now (so Windows 7 gets restored), will I be allowed to upgrade again?**

I read somewhere that it did not work for someone, second time it went technically fine, but upgrade was rejected from licensing viewpoint.

Comment: Take a look pls: http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/prevent-windows-10-upgrade-installing-after-making-your-reservation

Comment: "I read somewhere that it did not work for someone"  Can you provide a link to this?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 – the problem was, it's far from English language :)

Comment: @miroxlav - So provide the link, and translate within the question body, what you read.

Comment: @Ramhound – thank you for your interest in the question. I already declined the EULA, reverted to Windows 7 and I'll add correct answer from the first hand later, once I upgrade (if someone who tried the same won't be faster).

Comment: What you have done is simply revert back to Windows 7, the fact you didn't complete the WIndows 10 setup or agree to the EULA, doesn't change anything except for the fact your Windows 10 installation was activated.  Which means you should have allowed the setup to finish then revert back, to avoid having to perform the upgrade again, to recieve the free upgrade.

Comment: @Ramhound – do you think it is probable that declining the EULA could have activated Windows 10 licence? From law viewpoint, it looks improbable... To me it looks more likely that the licence wasn't activated. Computer's networking was disabled when computer was at EULA screen (which was visible at network monitoring device) so no communication with the Microsoft was made.

Comment: I meant to actually say your installation *wasn't** activated hence the reason you should have allowed it to finish then revert back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go here and download the upgrade and run it again:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-upgrade

Comment: I updated the question. I read somewhere that second time the upgrade did not work from licensing viewpoint.

Comment: Did you try the link i provided?

Comment: @miroxlav - There isn't anything to quote.  The answer is literally, just download this tool, and upgrade to Windows 10 when you so desire.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question about whether they can try the upgrade later is they decline the EULA now.

Comment: @Ramhound – please, did you read the *entire* question? This answer is not very useful.

Comment: I didn't actually say it was helpful.  I simply indicated that this answer, is is simply suggesting how to install Windows 10, specifically by using the Media Creation Tool.  I simply recgonize that there isn't anything to quote from the releated link.

Comment: @miroxlav Ramhound is making a comment not an Answer, huge difference.